# Where is the play framework maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, playframework

Trying to get my code to compile magically using maven dependancies. I can't find the playframework on any 3rd party maven repository.

Can someone help ? I is even deployed anywhere ?

Answer (score 17):

In typesafe Repo

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>typesafe</id>
    <name>typesafe-releases</name>
    <url>https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

The dependency is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>play</groupId>
  <artifactId>play_2.9.1</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Though for some of us, we are looking how to do it for Play 2 - so this turned out to be very useful :D

Comment: I'm getting `[INFO] Unable to find resource ...` with the above pom changes. Where can I find the correct `artifacId` and `version`? Looking at this url - http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/play/play_2.9.1/2.0.2/, it looks like it exists.

Comment: @MaFO - yes I'm using `Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.7.0_51`

Comment: I have the same maven version, I try now with a test pom and using 'mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=lib' and I don't have problems.

Comment: Intellij IDEA says there are no repositories found there

Answer (score 2):

It looks like using Maven with Play! will require some special "Maven module". I'm not sure to understand the difference between the [Maven support](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven-head/home) and the [maven module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/maven) pages though.

Have a look at the following thread for some background:

- [Play Framework with Maven?](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/702a023309f2beee)
- [Maven Module Created](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/d3310500ca3170c5)
- [Play + Maven issue???](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/cd07480253379113/ac474ecbd1e0c3ad)

Comment: The maven module assumes you already have Play installed on your disk. This is NOT what I want. I want to download the whole play distribution using Maven, the way I used to do it with OpenEJB. This way I can magically compile my eclipse project without hardcoded references in the classpath

Comment: @Olivier I understand that this is not exactly what you asked. Still, that's the only maven related  stuff I'm aware of.

Comment: After a few days, think I finally got it: there is no repository with the play framework deployed. So this question will probably never get answered.

Answer (score 1):

Play 1 has not been Mavenised, and likely will not be - but Play 2 uses sbt, which downloads Play and its dependencies from Maven repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Play 1.x and Play2 are not deployed on Maven repository. Plus, play is not intend to be use from a maven build. It's not a typical Java project where you pull your resources with a pom.xml. You need to download and install locally play framework on your server. Then do a local compilation from there.

Dependencies are handled with Apache Ivy for Play 1.x and SBT for Play 2.

To install Play 1.x, you can now also use "brew install play". This configures and installs play. It adds play to your path.

Play2 relies on SBT, a build tool for Scala that is similar to Maven.

Forget about Maven :-)

Comment: Sadly running tests from CI tools right now is pretty hard without maven, so some of us need it.

Comment: Maven is great for any scale java libraries/applications, it has its learning curve but after you're done with the first few knots it's a blast using it. Maven may be "archaic" but it's wrapped around java developing so good, it's a shame not using it.

Comment: Not anyone has got the option to "just download xyz" and run it locally. Often, and typically in enterprise setup, the build environment is just "set" and out of discussion.