# Types$TypeError: bad > symbolic reference

Tags: java, scala, maven, playframework

I ran into the following compile-time error on my Scala and Java code-base with the `maven-scala-plugin`.

> [ERROR] Caused by: scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad
>   symbolic reference. A signature in Json.class refers to term iteratee

Note that I had manually installed the `play_2.10-2.1.5.jar` from the Typesafe [repo](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/play/play_2.10/2.1.5/) as my added Maven dependency (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11309132/409976)) did not work.

There's a `play_iteratees` library available from the same [repo](http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/play/play-iteratees_2.10/), but I don't want to blindly keep adding dependencies before understanding what's wrong.

Looking at a similarly worded [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353297/bad-symbolic-reference-in-sbt-scala-project), I've already run `mvn clean` before trying to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `play-iteratees` JAR with the same version as my `play` JAR fixed the issue.

TypeSafe repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/play/play-iteratees_2.10/